# How do I add in code a System.ComponentModel.Container to form1 ? Getting ambiguity error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In top of form1 I added:

```
private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
```

Then in a private method I created I did:

```
private void NotifyIconSettings()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        }
```

But I'm getting error on the line: on the this.components

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
```

Error   1   Ambiguity between 'Pop3_Emails.Form1.components' and 'Pop3_Emails.Form1.components'

And I don't want to use the Pop3_Emails.Form1.components

Update

What i tried now is in the form1 constructor added:

```
contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add("&Open Application");
contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add("S&uspend Application");
contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add("E&xit");
notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
notifyIcon1.Text = "Right-click me!";
notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1;
```

So now right click on the icon in the tray icon i see the menus but how do i add now a click event and handle each menu item ? I mean when i click on Exit so the program will Exit. Now it does nothing.

Comment: Why do you need to try to use that?

Comment: I don't need you right. I edited my question now with what i tried.

Comment: You should be using the ContextMenuStrip instead.  It replaced the ContextMenu version.  One of the add parameters is for the event handler, so you will have to write the method for that beforehand.